# Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: usingExperimentalRuntime in GAE MemCache

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Whenever I try to access MemCache I get a `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: usingExperimentalRuntime`. No documentation on that field from what I can find. Is there some configuration option that I'm not aware of?

Here's the source code:

```
MemcacheService syncCache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
syncCache.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandlers.getConsistentLogAndContinue(Level.ALL));

Object cacheObject = syncCache.get("arbitrary");
```

That last line crashes with this error (partial stack trace up to my code):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: usingExperimentalRuntime
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb$MemcacheGetRequest.writeTo(MemcacheServicePb.java:1511)
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.toByteArray(AbstractMessageLite.java:41)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper.makeAsyncCall(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:97)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.doGet(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:405)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.getIdentifiable(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:422)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.getIdentifiable(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:54)
        at com.myCode.CacheOrDbUtil.getUser(CacheOrDbUtil.java:27)
```

What makes this so strange is that the code was working last week, complete with unit tests using MemCache. Now they are failing. Of course I've tried undoing everything I've done, but without success:

- Upgrading gcloud
- Downgrading gcloud
- Shutting down all other servers
- Rebooting the machine
- Reset to last known good code revision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either stay with 1.9.48 (out of the box in the Cloud SDK for now, upgraded next week to 1.9.49) and make sure your pom.xml/gradle build files are all using 1.9.48,
or use the standard appengine Maven plugin from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.49</version>
</plugin>
```

or equivalent Gradle plugin for AppEngine (not the Cloud SDK one..)

Comment: I set gradle to use 1.9.48 for both test and dev servers and everything worked. Thanks! Before the dev was set to use the latest (the '+' version in gradle) and the test to use 1.9.46. Setting both to 1.9.49 didn't work for the dev server. The latest stable release worked though.

Answer (score 1):

We had to push everything to 1.9.49 to get it to work. I'm not sure why Maven doesn't list it on the website yet...

It's there -- it's just not listed:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.49/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.49.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try to update appEngineVersion to 1.9.49

Comment: I did an update yesterday before making the original post and it only took app-engine-java to version 1.9.48. The python version is 1.9.49, but I'm not using Python. Where could I get the 1.9.49 version of the java engine?